# How to give back constant if node does not exist in XPATH?

Tags: xml, xpath, ssis

I have a problem, consider the following XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/>     
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/>    
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

I have to work with SSIS. I would like to get all data to SSIS variables in a for each loop for all Order entries. So far I can get data with a ForeachLoop in control flow in SSIS, with the following:

```
EnumerationType:  ElementCollection
OuterXPathString: //*[name() = 'ORDER']
InnerElementType: NodeText
InnerXPathString: @*[name() = 'EngineID'] | @*[name() = 'OrderID'] | child::node()/@*[name() = 'InstID'] | child::node()/@*[name() = 'SeqID']
```

**How can I get the OtherInfo data in such a way, that it would always give back something, even if the node does not exist?** Example, if the node does not exist, give back "No".

On the discussion side, I need this, because the SSIS mapping use integer indexing on the result set. If the result set can be 4 or 5 long, I get index out of bounds error. This is my idea to circumvent the problem, to always return a fixed length result set.

If this can't be done, the other idea would be to expand the XML with default values. So in case the other question is: **Can you show me, how to add default values to an XML with XPATH?** Example: Make the mentioned XML to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
<ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/>     
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67" OtherInfo="yes"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/>    
</ORDER>
<ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68" OtherInfo="defaultvalue"><INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/></ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

Or is there a more elegant way of solving this in SSIS?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **How can I get the OtherInfo data in such a way, that it would always
>   give back something, even if the node does not exist?** Example, if the
>   node does not exist, give back "No".

**Here is one way to produce the value of the `OtherInfo` attribute if this attribute exists or the string `"no"` otherwise**:

```
      concat(@OtherInfo,
             substring('no',1 + 2*boolean(@OtherInfo)))
```

**When this Xpath 1.0 expression is evaluated on the following element:**

```
    <ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="yes">
            <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/>
```

the result is:

```
yes
```

**But when the same expression is evaluated on:**

```
    <ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68">
            <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/>
```

then the result is:

```
no
```

**XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/*/*">
         <xsl:value-of select=
         "concat(@OtherInfo,
                 substring('no',1 + 2*boolean(@OtherInfo)))
         "/>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on the provided XML document:**

```
<APIDATA xmlns="api-com">
        <ORDER EngineID="1" OrderID="66" OtherInfo="yes">
                <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="27" SeqID="17"/>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER EngineID="2" OrderID="67" OtherInfo="yes">
                <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="28" SeqID="18"/>
        </ORDER>
        <ORDER EngineID="3" OrderID="68">
                <INSTSPECIFIER InstID="29" SeqID="19"/>
        </ORDER>
</APIDATA>
```

**The Xpath expression is evaluated against each `ORDER` element and the result of the evaluation is copied to the output**:

```
yesyesno
```

**Explanation**:

The expression:

```
      concat(@OtherInfo,
             substring('no',1 + 2*boolean(@OtherInfo)))
```

produces the concatenation of two strings.

**In case the context node has an attribute named `OtherInfo`,** then the second string is the empty string and only the first string (the value of the attribute) is produced.

**In case the context node has no attribute named `OtherInfo`**, then the first argument of `concat()` is the empty string and the second argument is evaluated and output.

How is this subexpression evaluated in each of these two cases:

```
substring('no',1 + 2*boolean(@OtherInfo))
```

1. **If `@OtherInfo` exists**. Then `2*boolean(@OtherInfo) = 2*true() = 2*1 = 2` Therefore, the expression is equivalent to: `substring('no',3)` and this is the empty string, because `"no"` has a length of only 2.
2. **If `@OtherInfo` doesn't exist**. Then `2*boolean(@OtherInfo) = 2*false() = 2*0 = 0`. Therefore, the expression is equivalent to: `substring('no',1)` and this evaluates to the string `"no"`.

Comment: The explanation is very helpful, however, `2*boolean(@OtherInfo)` will return an error `Error: Arithmetic operator is not defined for provided arguments`. Instead I used something like this to get this to work
`concat(@OtherInfo,  substring('no', 1+2*number(boolean(string-length(@OtherInfo)>0))))`

Comment: @Yadu This answer was provided in the context of the question (XPath 1.0).
In XPath 2.0 there is no problem to get the wanted result, for example use: `(@OtherInfo, 'no'[not(@otherInfo)])`